# Why I am getting PluginResolutionException?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, maven

I am working on NetBeans 7.0 which has maven 3.0.3 by default.... last week I opened a project which was developed using Maven 2.2... Now even after closing that project.. NetBeans is not allowing me to create  any new project...not even the sample projects of NetBeans.... Every time I get the following error ...

```
    Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.4.3: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:pom:2.4.3 from/to central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): Error transferring file: repo1.maven.org: Unknown host repo1.maven.org -> [Help 1]

    To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
    Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

    For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
    "**[Help 1] http://cw

iki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException"**
```

any help regarding this will be appreciated....

Thanks in advance,,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Unknown host repo1.maven.org

Try setting your DNS to `8.8.8.8` or `8.8.4.4` these are google's DNS which can resolve this name

in Linux machine.

type

```
sudo gedit /etc/resolv.conf
```

add an entry of nameserver with the mentioned IP

Comment: thanks @Jigar, but how I change the DNS name... ? in the main System Settings or in The NetBeans (unfortunately I cant find any such field in Netbeans IDE)....

Comment: thanks.... that worked... I was trying to solve this error for quite a few hours... u saved some more hours...thanks once again.....